# Create new field in a collection generated by lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document generated after using lookup:

[image]

As you can see user_posts is an array. I want to add a new field to each of the objects in the user_posts array and I want the value of it to be the same as _id of that object, I tried using $addFields as follows:

```
{"user_posts.post_id": { "$toString": "$(user_posts._id)" }}
```

as a result, a field named "post_id" is added to each object in the array, but its value is null, does anyone know a way around?

[image]

EDIT:
Using $addFields with the same arguments as above mentioned, but without converting it to string:

```
{ "user_posts.post_id": "$user_posts._id" }
```

adds an array to the post_id containing the _id of each object in array the parent array:

[image]

The only question I have right now, is how can I use $addField such that it adds a new field to each of the documents in the array, and the value of each added field is same as the _id of that document

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please post test instead of screenshots.

Comment: whats a test? @turivishal

Comment: It is *text content.